# Creating a type to extend React.Component with class attributes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to bring Typescript into a project that extends react components with various additional class properties. I'm trying to work out how to extend the React.Component type to incorporate those additional attributes.

As an example of what I mean, in both class and functional form:

```
class SampleComponent extends React.Component<{}, {}> {}
const OtherComponent: React.SFC<{}> = (props) => <div/>

SampleComponent.importantClassProp = "Hello StackOverflow"
OtherComponent.importantClassProp = "I need help."
```

The closest I've been able to get thus far has been the following, which only works for purely functional components and makes the additional prop optional (since it's technically set after component declaration, making the attribute mandatory would be amazing).

```
interface SpecialComponent<P = {}> extends React.StatelessComponent<InputProps & P> {
   specialKey?: string;
}
const Component: SpecialComponent<{}> = props => <div/>
Component.specialKey = "Yo"
```